# SQL -- How is DISTINCT so fast without an index?

Tags: sql, database, optimization, sqlite

I have a database with a table called 'links' with 600 million rows in it in SQLite. There are 2 columns in the database - a "src" column and a "dest" column. At present there are no indices.

There are a fair number of common values between src and dest, but also a fair number of duplicated rows.

The first thing I'm trying to do is remove all the duplicate rows, and then perform some additional processing on the results, however I've been encountering some weird issues.

Firstly, `SELECT * FROM links WHERE src=434923 AND dest=5010182`. Now this returns one result fairly quickly and then takes quite a long time to run as I assume it's performing a tablescan on the rest of the 600m rows.

However, if I do `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM links`, then it immediately starts returning rows really quickly. The question is: how is this possible?? Surely for each row, the row must be compared against all of the other rows in the table, but this would require a tablescan of the remaining rows in the table which **SHOULD** takes ages!

Any ideas why `SELECT DISTINCT` is so much quicker than a standard `SELECT`?

Comment: Are there any primary keys in your database?

Comment: What's the schema of the table? (Feel free to anonymize.)

Comment: if you repeatedly read the SQLite file it will end up in the OS page cache. So repeated reads might be hitting RAM and not disk. Depends on the size of your RAM vs DB and what else is happening on the box.

Comment: @Spike 600 million rows fit in page cache? Even if that were possible, how does that explain one scan being faster than the other? they'd both be reading from memory

Comment: Imagine both queries running in realtime at the same time. Both are doing a full table scan. Both read row 1, then row 2, then row 3, then row 4, determining if they match your query and should be sent to you. For the first query, most of the rows don't match, so you see no output and just wait. For the second, most of the rows do match, so you see them scrolling by. Same exact speed, the second just FEELS quicker.

Comment: Merged your accounts.  Jeff wants to keep the site easy to use for new people, but the design tends to trick newbs into creating multiple accounts.  Thanks for registering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it. With no ordering applied it can return results in scan order. It just keeps a list (more likely, an efficient struct like a b-tree) of the values seen so far. If a given value isn't found it's returned and added to the bookkeeping structure. Absolutely no need to compare with all the other rows at all.

Comment: This is a good answer, and it makes sense (silly me for not realising this earlier).

However: are we sure it puts it in a b-tree, or does it just create a temporary table-like store which grows larger and larger and needs to be scanned start to finish for each row?

Comment: B-tree is just an assumption. However, a b-tree will generally be much faster for membership testing than a full scan (O(logN) vs O(N))

Comment: I realise b-tree has the advantage of O(logN), which is why I really hope that the SQLite implementation of DISTINCT uses a b-tree for temp storage -- can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

To be more accurate, one query is not quicker than the other. More precisely, the amount of time taken until the query is completed should be the same for both queries. The difference is that the query with DISTINCT simply has more rows to return therefore it appears to respond faster since you are recieving rows at a fast rate. However, what is happening under the hood of both is the same table scan. The distinct query has a data structure storing what has been returned and filters duplicates. Therefore, it SHOULD actually take longer until the query completes but (rows returned)/time is larger since there are simply more rows that match. (Also note: some viewers add a query result limit which can make the distinct query appear to run faster (since you hit the result limit and stop)).

Comment: +1.  A little convoluted, but I agree with the basic premise.  Fetching the rows from disk/memory isn't the bottleneck.  Data transfer is the bottleneck, so fewer rows = faster.